# Why is this call to implicitly ambiguous?

Tags: scala, implicit

The signature of the `sum` method on `TraversableOnce` is as follows:

```
def sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B = foldLeft(num.zero)(num.plus)
```

I can use it thus:

```
scala> (1 to 10).sum
res0: Int = 55
```

In this case, the compiler is injecting the `Numeric[B]` itself, so there must be an unambiguous implicit value of this type in scope. If I use `Predef.implicitly` to inject it myself, this happens:

```
scala> (1 to 10).sum(implicitly)
<console>:6: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method conforms in object Predef of type [A]<:<[A,A]
 and method stringCanBuildFrom in object Predef of type => scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]
 match expected type T
   (1 to 10).sum(implicitly)
                 ^
```

**Why is this ambiguous?**

*I can make the ambiguity disappear either by*

```
scala> (1 to 10).sum(implicitly[Numeric[Int]])
res2: Int = 55
```

*Or*

```
scala> (1 to 10).sum[Int](implicitly)
res3: Int = 55
```

I presume that this has something to do with the fact that sum declares a new type parameter `B >: A` (*it clearly is, see below edit*), but I'm still confused about why something can be unambiguously found in the first example but not the second?

**EDIT** - *to address subsub's inane comment (below)*

```
scala> class As[A](as : A*) { 
 | def sum(implicit num : Numeric[A]) : A = as.foldLeft(num.zero)(num.plus) 
 | }
defined class As

scala> (new As(1, 2, 3, 4)).sum
res0: Int = 10

scala> (new As(1, 2, 3, 4)).sum(implicitly)
res1: Int = 10
```

*So, you can see that it is not the case that any call to implicitly is ambiguous*

Comment: It's as ambiguous as any call to implicitly. `scala> Predef.implicitly
<console>:6: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method conforms in object Predef of type [A]<:<[A,A]
 and method stringCanBuildFrom in object Predef of type => scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]
 match expected type T
       Predef.implicitly`. So possibly the underlying meaning is something along the lines of "didn't find any suitable implicit thing here, please help!"

Comment: @subsub - see my edit. That's exactly what is going on; I'm asking why the call to implicitly is being inferred as resulting in an ambiguous implicit. If there are matching implicit values in cope, why is the no-param call having similar problems?

Comment: if my comment was inane why did you edit your question?  
Well, here's another one: `class Bs[A](bs : TraversableOnce[A]) { def sum(implicit num : Numeric[A]) : A = bs.foldLeft(num.zero)(num.plus) }; (new Bs(1 to 10)).sum(implicitly) `

Comment: To prove to you how inane it was. I asked why a call to `implicitly` was ambiguous in a **specific case**. You answered: "well, it's ambiguous over here" *for a completely different case*!

Comment: interestingly the accepted answer includes that inane completely different case ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Because of `B >: A` resulting type for `implicitly` call can not be inferred.

Longer answer. When argument defined as `implicit` is missing, compiler will search current scope for any implicit value of type `Numeric[B >: Int]` and will use the most specific - `Numeric[Int]`.

But if you specify argument as `implicitly` (a call to the `implicitly [T] (implicit e: T) : T`) first the type argument `T` must be resolved. And scala runtime clearly fails to do so.

It is the same as calling this:

```
scala> var f = implicitly
 <console>:5: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method conforms in object Predef of type [A]<:<[A,A]
 and method stringCanBuildFrom in object Predef of type =>     scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]
 match expected type T
       var f = implicitly
               ^
```